# Mismatch in calculation in Python

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
b=np.matrix("2,1,2;1,0,1;3,1,3")
det_b = np.linalg.det(b)
print(round(det_b,10)) 
inv_b = np.linalg.inv(b)
print(inv_b)
```

when I run this code it gives some matrix, but inverse of this matrix doesn't exist as determinant of this matrix is zero. But this code gives the output as follow

Output:

```
[[-6.0047995e+15 -6.0047995e+15  6.0047995e+15]
 [ 1.0000000e+00 -2.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00]
 [ 6.0047995e+15  6.0047995e+15 -6.0047995e+15]]
```

Someone help me to get rid of it. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: When executing your code I have a `LinAlgError: Singular matrix`. np.__version__ = 1.19.5

Comment: I just ran your code. it gives error meaning the code is working. try updating your numpy and python versions